# Acceder a funcion desde otra actividad

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo estas dos funciones ubicadas en la Mainactivity:

Función para mostrar la pantalla home:

```
private fun showHome(correo: String, proveedor: ProviderType) {

    val intent1: Intent = Intent(this, Activity1::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("correo", correo)
        putExtra("proveedor", proveedor.name)
    }
    startActivity(intent1)
}
```

Función para mostrar advertencias en caso de que el registro no sea correcto:

```
private fun showAlertSing() {

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Error")
    builder.setMessage("Se ha producido un error registrando al usuario, puede que ya esté registrado.")
    builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null)
    val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
}
```

Y por último este es el código que ejecuta dichas funciones al pulsar un textview:

```
 //textview registro
    textviewRegister.setOnClickListener {
        if (emailRegisterEditText.text.isNotEmpty() && passwordRegisterEditText.text.isNotEmpty()) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            //creamos el nuevo usuario
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            emailEditText.text.toString(),
            passwordEditText.text.toString()
            ).addOnCompleteListener {
        // si el registro es correcto permitimos el acceso a la app
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
            showHome(it.result?.user?.email ?: "", ProviderType.BASIC)
            } else {
            //si el registro es incorrecto llamamos a showalert para que notifique el error
            showAlertSing()
            }
        }
            }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Debes indicar una dirección de correo válida y una contraseña para poder realizar el registro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return@setOnClickListener
        }
     }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anteriormente el código funcionaba correctamente pero al ubicarlas en otra actividad no localiza dichas funciones. He probado a cambiar el modificador de visibilidad a "public" pero el problema persiste. ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal y como puedo solucionarlo? Gracias.

Comment: he agregado una respuesta, debes usar "companion object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Para poder llamar los métodos desde otra clase, agrégalos dentro de un `companion object`**, de esta forma podrás llamarlos pero en este caso agrega como parámetro el contexto:

```
   companion object {        

        fun showHome(ctx: Context, correo: String, proveedor: Int) {
            val intent1: Intent = Intent(ctx, Activity1::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("correo", correo)
                putExtra("proveedor", proveedor)
            }
            ctx.startActivity(intent1)
        }

        fun showAlertSing(ctx: Context) {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(ctx)
            builder.setTitle("Error")
            builder.setMessage("Se ha producido un error registrando al usuario, puede que ya esté registrado.")
            builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null)
            val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
            dialog.show()
        }

    }
```

Esta sería una forma de llamarlos desde otra clase usando el contexto, asegura agregar su respectivo import:

```
    showHome(this,"jorgesys12@hotmail.com", 12)
    showAlertSing(this)
```

Comment: Por si a alguien le sirve, en lugar de "showHome(this,"jorgesys12@hotmail.com", 12)" he puesto "showHome(this,it.result?.user?.email ?: "", "BASIC")" para pasar los datos del correo a registrar. Gracias por tu ayuda Jorge.